# How to statically set JMX port (not rmi-registry) in glassfish 3.1?

Tags: port, glassfish-3, jmx, firewall

**How can I instruct Glassfish 3.1.1 to use a static port for its JMX Server?** The RMI-Registry runs on the default port 8686, but the real JMX server uses a dynamic port. I want to set this port number statically so we can open a firewall port and manage Glassfish from remote machines.

I've searched through every stackoverflow and java.net topic but haven't found any working solutions.